# How to get keword argument from url in django class based views?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Is there any way to get keyword argument declared in url.py inside class based views methods?

For example: I want to override `get_initial(self)` to set one of the values to value from url. Do I really need to override `__init__` to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
arg_value = self.kwargs.get(ARGUMENT_NAME, None)
```

Which is how it is done in the `SingleObjectMixin`, which provides the get_object functionality used in `DetailView`.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L34